# Pillow API image.text command giving me error

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

Edit: thank you for the help (was stuck on this for an hour. Turns out I was using `ImageDraw2`, which it somehow tells me to import instead of just `ImageDraw`)

Here is my code:

```
import os
from PIL import Image, ImageFont, ImageDraw2

def OverlayImage(path):
    img = Image.open(path)
    Im = ImageDraw2.Draw(img)
    fill_color = (255, 255, 0)
    dafont = ImageFont.truetype('Memesique-Regular.ttf', 25)
    print("font done")
    Im.text((13, 37), "better work", font=dafont, fill=fill_color)
    img.show()
    img.save("meme-image.jpg")`
```

When I run this code, I keep getting the error:

```
Draw.text() got an unexpected keyword argument 'fill'
```

It seems like no matter where I look, everything online is saying to use `fill=fill_color`, and when I remove the keyword, it gives me a syntax error. When I try using any other keyword (e.g., 'color' instead of 'fill'), I get the error:

```
TypeError: Draw.text() got an unexpected keyword argument 'color'
```

Thank you in advance for help!

Comment: Removing the keyword cannot possibly give a syntax error, unless you made some other basic mistake.  Please show us the line of code you tried to remove that keyword.

Comment: `ImageDraw`'s `text()` method does indeed take a `fill=` parameter - *but that's not what you're using here*.  You're using `ImageDraw2` instead, which seems to be an abandoned experimental module (last update in 2005!).

Answer (score 0):

Try using the ImageDraw module and not ImageDraw2.
The ImageDraw2 module is depreciated.

```py
from PIL import ImageDraw, ImageFont 

# Creating a Draw object 
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img) 

fnt = ImageFont.truetype("Pillow/Tests/fonts/FreeMono.ttf", 10) 
  
# Drawing the text on the image 
draw.text(xy=(25, 160), text="Hello world", font=fnt, fill=(0, 127, 0)) 
  
img.show()
```